# Padding not working as expected, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's 500px in width, and 500px in height. The max-width and max-height are also set to 500px. I'm trying to make the padding-left of the div to be 100px so I can move the word "Hello" 100px from the left without increasing the overall width of the div. When I set the padding-left to 100px, the overall width of my div increased to 600px, even though I set the max-width of the div to be only 500px. Is there a way for me to move the word "Hello" 100px from the left without having the width of the div being increased, or wrapping another element around the word "Hello"?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ willhelp you understand the box model

Comment: 100px + 400px = 500px. give width `400px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `box-sizing: border-box`, so as to force the declared height to take into account your padding(s).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Also, is there a way for me to place a border straight in the middle of the div, from top to bottom?

Comment: @frosty You can (1) use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element for that or (2) use a background gradient trick.

Comment: I need it to adjust automatically with the height of the div without having to manually adjust the height of the div because I'm using this border trick in a forum, and the height of the forums depends on how many posts there are.

Comment: @frosty You don't need to define the height: if you use `top: 0; bottom: 0` on an absolutely positioned element it will stretch to the height of the closest relatively positioned parent.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do it without placing it inside the parent?

Comment: @frosty This question is at risk of turning into a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)—if you have a separate issue, open a new question ;)

Comment: Nevermind. I'll just put it inside the parent then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust your box model. Put this in your CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[Paul Irish explains how the box model works](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and why we have to define it this way.

Essentially, when we use `padding` it adds itself to the value of the inner width/height. By adjusting your box-sizing to `border-box` you're saying that if your box is 500px wide, and you apply `padding-left: 100px`, it will simulate the box being only 400px to compensate for the padding - to give a total of 500px.

[Browser support is universal](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) at this point, and it performs well (despite the use of the `*` selector, which has as much of an impact as use HTML tags like `h1` and `p` in CSS).

**UPDATE:** Note that the CSS above affects **all** elements that use the box-model. Whenever I update one box-model on a stylesheet, I update them all to prevent overlooking this detail later in the game when I am attempting to maintain continuity.

Comment: Why mess with `*` when all you need is to fix one box?

Comment: Inconsistent box-models is something I've overlooked before, so to spare confusion - when I change one box-model on a stylesheet, I change them all. I will adjust my answer though to address this. @SalmanA